# nginx redirect remote URL to local files

Tags: nginx

Trying to do something simple (I think) but stumped on how to get there. It doesn’t help that I’m new to nginx. I’ve read through various posts and anything else I could find.

I want to configure nginx to redirect all requests to a specific URL to a folder on localhost. For instance, the following requests:

```
https://www.example.com/alpha/beta/gamma
https://www.example.com/alpha/beta/gamma/index.html
https://www.example.com/alpha/beta/gamma/assets/images/friend.png
https://www.example.com/alpha/beta/gamma/main.ce6329ef0ed8aa52d583.bundle.js
```

would serve up the following files:

```
/Users/flynn/Projects/new-ui/dist/index.html
/Users/flynn/Projects/new-ui/dist/index.html
/Users/flynn/Projects/new-ui/dist/assets/images/friend.png
/Users/flynn/Projects/new-ui/dist/main.ce6329ef0ed8aa52d583.bundle.js
```

All other requests to URLs starting with `https://www.example.com` would not be redirected but just passed through. Those requests would return responses as well as set cookies that should be automatically sent back.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried an `alias` directive? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.